# Try to create sinch client when require throw error

Tags: android, sinch

Below following  log error i have got when try to create sinch client

```
E/sinch-android-rtc: ERROR: sqlite Failed to exec 'PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL', error: database is locked (code: 5, extended code: 5)
11-20 18:22:54.535 1 E/sinch-android-rtc: ERROR: sqlite Failed to execute: PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL
11-20 18:22:54.535 E/sinch-android-rtc: ERROR: sqlite Failed to execute: PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL
11-20 18:22:54.535 ERROR: sqlite Failed to execute PRAGMAs (IM)
11-20 18:22:54.535 E/sinch-android-rtc: ERROR: sqlite Failed to execute PRAGMAs (IM)
11-20 18:22:54.680 W/SinchClient: onStartFailed()
11-20 18:22:59.253 D/SinchClient: terminate()
```

And following error in when listen onFailed in sinch

```
SinchError[errorType=OTHER, code=6002, message='Failed to initialize messaging', data={}]
```

what can be possible reason for this error.

Comment: are you starting multiple instances of the client? you should only have one.

Comment: thank you for reply sir. Yeah you are right. Due to little mistake i am calling multiple times to sinch client. now problem is resolved.